# jQuery progress bar not working for firefox only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, firefox

I have created a page for uploading of single file and I wanted to include a progress bar to track the progress. It is working perfectly on chrome (and not so perfectly on IE and edge but still I can give and take a bit). However the progress bar and the relevant `document.getElementById()` are not working properly. Firefox jumped to display

> Upload failed

Instead of displaying my progress bar animation and the relevant uploading data such as number of bytes uploaded. What is weird is that my file does eventually get uploaded and I was redirected to the success page. What is even weirder is when I tried to use firefox debugging tool to step over my code line by line, the progress bar and upload data are displayed correctly.

PS. These were only tested on localhost.

**uploadfile.php**
HTML part

```
<form action="getfile.php" id="upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
    Type (or select) Filename: <input type="file" id="file1" name="uploadfile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
    <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
    <h3 id="status"></h3>
    <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
```

script part

```
function uploadFile() {
    var file = document.getElementById("file1").files[0];
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "getfile.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event) {
    document.getElementById("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    document.getElementById("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event) {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    document.getElementById("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler() {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler() {
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to avoid depricrated methods.

```
 var myXhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
 if (myXhr.upload) {
     myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', custom_progress, false);
 }
```

Then Handle the progress

```
function custom_progress(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        var x = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
        jQuery("#progress").html(x + "%");
    }
}
```

for complete ajax method

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/uploadfile.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    xhr: function() {
        var myXhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (myXhr.upload) {
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', custom_progress, false);
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```